# Angular 9 Adding Multiple Objects in an array overrides the existing array

Tags: angular, angular9

I am using Angular 9 and am trying to add multiple objects in an array. But I see that on adding the new object the existing objects also gets changed. I suspect that is because the array has a reference to the object.

How do I change that.

Code:

```
userModel: UserModel = new UserModel()
userArray: any = new Array()

.....codes..constructors....oninits etc...

submit(){
    this.userModel.name = "Hello"
    this.userModel.age = "25"
    this.userModel.area = "IN"

    this.userArray.push(this.userModel)

    this.userModel.name = "World"
    this.userModel.age = "26"
    this.userModel.area = "WB"

    this.userArray.push(this.userModel)
}
```

The Output is

[{'name':'World, 'age':'26', 'area':'WB'},{'name':'World, 'age':'26', 'area':'WB'}]

What I want is

[{'name':'Hello, 'age':'25', 'area':'IN'},{'name':'World, 'age':'26', 'area':'WB'}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pushing the same reference into the array everytime (this.userModel), without reassigning to a different object. Hence, this.userArray[0] and this.userArray[1] are the same object, and changes made to item at one index or this.userModel will affect the other. Try

```
submit(){
    this.userModel.name = "Hello"
    this.userModel.age = "25"
    this.userModel.area = "IN"

    this.userArray.push(this.userModel)

    this.userModel = {} as any; // reassign the reference to a new Object

    this.userModel.name = "World"
    this.userModel.age = "26"
    this.userModel.area = "WB"

    this.userArray.push(this.userModel)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `this.userArray.push(this.userModel)`,
you will have to change it to `this.userArray.push({ ...this.userModel })` at both the places.

This will fix your error.

The mistake you are doing is:

`userModel` variable stores the reference to the object and the same object is pushed as reference to the array when you do `this.userArray.push(this.userModel)`.

So if you change `userModel` again, you are changing the object referenced by all the other variables.

Answer (score 1):

when you access **this.userModel.name** is refer to the same object. So You need to create a new UserModel Object and set values before pushing to the array.

you can do it simply like below

```
submit() {
    this.userModel.name = "Hello"
    this.userModel.age = "25"
    this.userModel.area = "IN"

    this.userArray.push({...this.userModel})

    this.userModel.name = "World"
    this.userModel.age = "26"
    this.userModel.area = "WB"

    this.userArray.push({...this.userModel})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @Kaustubh said, you're just changing the same object and pushing it onto the array again.

Another way to do this would be to use the spread operator when pushing, to copy the object, rather than pushing the original.  I like this better, since the array ends up with a copy instead of the original object.

```
submit() {
    this.userModel.name = "Hello"
    this.userModel.age = "25"
    this.userModel.area = "IN"

    this.userArray.push({ ...this.userModel })

    this.userModel.name = "World"
    this.userModel.age = "26"
    this.userModel.area = "WB"

    this.userArray.push({ ...this.userModel })
}
```